# Increment a number inside a div?

Tags: jquery, html

i have this

`<div class="likes">13</div>`

and I want to increment this number by +1 when I click a button

How can I do that with jQuery?

```
$('btn').click(function() {
   $('.likes').text();
});
```

Comment: `$('.likes').text(function(i,txt){ return parseInt(txt,10) + 1; })`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
$('btn').click(function() {
  var el = parseInt($('.likes').text());
  $('.likes').text(el+1);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jg5GA/

Comment: Oh no, let me refactor that for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try following

```
$('.likes').click(function() {
   $(this).text(+($(this).text()) + 1);
});
```

(edited my initial post)

Answer (score 2):

```
var jLikes = $('div.likes');
var sLikes = jLikes.text();
var nLikes = parseInt(sLikes);
if(isNaN(nLikes)) {
   return;
}
jLikes.text(nLikes+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/4Wxkq/1/

```
var value = $('.likes').text();
    value++;
```