# on click increment a button text using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating buttons on click I would like to increment button text on every time a user creates a new button

HTML

```
<button id="btn">Add button</button>

<div id="movie-block">

</div>

$("#btn").on("click", function(){
   var newMovieBlockButton = $("<div class='movie-button w'>Button1<div>");
    $("#movieblock" + movieid).append(newMovieBlockButton);
})
```

I want when user click add button new button should be created starting with eg 
 `button1`, if he creates another button it should be `button2` etc etc

How can I accomplish that using jquery?

Comment: create a counter. increment it on click and concat with the button  text ?

Comment: `$("<div/>",{ "class":"movie-button w", "text": "Button"+$(".movie-button").length}).appendTo($movieBlock);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each click, you can take the *length* of the button with class `movie-button` and concatenate that with the text:

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function(){
   var len = $('.movie-button').length + 1;
   var newMovieBlockButton = $("<div class='movie-button w'>Button"+ len +"<div>");
   
    $("#movie-block").append(newMovieBlockButton);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Add button</button>

<div id="movie-block">

</div>
```

Comment: I am sure this would solve the issue but you should also consider adding an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

[A quick google search would have helped.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510272/increment-a-number-inside-a-div)

```
<button id="btn">Add button</button>

<div id="movie-block">

</div>

let counter = 1;
$("#btn").on("click", function(){
   var newMovieBlockButton = $(`<div class='movie-button w'>Button${counter}<div>`);
    $("#movieblock" + movieid).append(newMovieBlockButton);
    counter++;
})
```

Comment: More elegant to count the buttons

Comment: @mplungjan Depends on the use-case. There might be another section of `.movie-button`, which should have a separate counter. Might be a personal opinion, but I don't consider this as "elegant".

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="append()">Try it</button>
<div id="myDIV">
New Paragraphs will add on this div
</div>
<script>
function append() {
  var para = document.createElement("P");
  para.innerHTML = "This is a paragraph.";
  document.getElementById("myDIV").appendChild(para);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help